# Is it possible to use different skins in a class based on some conditions?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

We are building an application which is using skin classes in mxml. 
We plan to build different variants of this application for different user segments, where most of the functionality remains same but only skins vary based on the user segment.

We are adding skins to the application by the following syntax:

```
<s:BorderContainer id="Banner" height="15%" width="100%" skinClass="mySkins.backgroundSkin"/>
```

Is there a way we can have a skin based on some condition
i.e if `usersegment = "A"` then use `myskins.backgroundSkin1`, else use `myskins.backgroundSkin2`?

Answer (score 3):

Creat a stylesheet for each user segment where you define the skin classes mapping.

Then you can invoke your stylesheet at runtime with :

```
styleManager.loadStyleDeclarations("yourStylesheet.swf")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also set the skin with actionscript like:

```
if (usersegment == "A")
  Banner.setStyle("skinClass", mySkins.backgroundSkin1);
else
  Banner.setStyle("skinClass", mySkins.backgroundSkin2);
```

Comment: Sorry for the vote down, but I don't think this is the way to go about it at all. This would hard code a dependency on the user segment when all you need to do is load a different style decleration. PS: sorry again if this isn't how the vote down system should be used (I'm a newb on this site still) :)